# NRWL NX importing lib error TS2307: Cannot find module '@eduboard/interfaces'

Tags: angular, angular7, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I've just created a new NX project for work and I've created a lib for out interfaces to have them on the backend and the front end.

I'm getting this error when I compile

```
apps/askeddi/src/app/pages/global-admin/global-admin.component.ts(5,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@eduboard/interfaces'.
```

From everything i have read is that i have done nothing wrong but its asking for a module and its just an index.ts file.

```
export * from './lib/user';
export * from './lib/global-admin-dashboard';
```

And this the global-admin-dashboard

```
interface Schools {
  total: number;
  active: number;
  usingAssessor: number;
}

interface TotalNActive {
  total: number;
  active: number;
}

export interface GlobalAdminDashboard {
  schools: Schools;
  schoolGroups: TotalNActive;
  users: TotalNActive;
}
```

Comment: is there a path entry in your tsconfig.json file for your library?

Comment: Yeah. That's why I'm really confused

Comment: well it could be that there is a empty interfaces file in the template, that was the case in my nx project. just take a look at the index.ts in your lib and remove everything that is not necessary, also empty files.

Comment: Checked and none are empty still getting the no module

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found out how to fix my problem.

So inside the `tsconfig.app.json` file, I added this to the paths.

```
"@eduboard/interfaces" : [
  "../../../libs/interfaces/src/index"
  ]
```

I had to go back a fair few because I had it have a `baseURL` set to `src/`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me. The autogenerated path was not a relative one.

Comment: Overriding baseURL in local tsconfig.json meant that it wasn't working – but this fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @FloppyNotFound in which tsconfig did you update the path?

Comment: @Alex They should all be linked together but sometimes you have to do some trial and error. I've Had a problem where with the hierarchy over write what I've done.

Comment: @Skel thanks for getting back so fast! so in the root folder/tsconfig.base.json, I have `"paths": {
      "@lib-frontend/ui": ["libs/ui/src/index.ts"]
    }`, this is where I need to update the path?

Comment: @Alex In my latest project i have a `tsconfig.json` file that's just got references to the paths of the other files and inside my `tsconfig.app.json` it extends the `tsconfig.base.json` then inside that, I have my `"baseUrl": "./"` Then my paths set up to start from `src/` hope this helps

Answer (score 15):

You need to specify the location of your library for TypeScript to locate.

Add your library to the `tsconfig.json` at the root of your project under `"paths"`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "@package/my-lib": ["libs/my-lib/src/index.ts"]
    }
  }
}
```

*You may need to reload VSCode to have TypeScript reload the `tsconfig.json`.*

Comment: I don't know why your answer was voted down. It helped me. I added paths to a few different places and nothing worked until I created a new tsconfig.json file and let it extend the tsonconfig.base.json

Comment: I'm glad it could help you at least :)

Comment: Restarting my IDE after making these changes was needed for me

Answer (score 5):

nx team should pay some attention to this issue. I had same issue when I was trying out the tutorial on the nx.dev website.
I read on some other thread that if you delete the node_modules folder and re-run npm install, the issue disappears. I tried it and it worked. Really disappointing.

As mentioned in the other answer, I don't think you need to specify paths in every project where you use the library. That breaks some basic architectures/benefits provided by nx.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't come across that fix of deleting your node_modules file. Otherwise, I would have just done that.

Comment: Also, to note, this happens only for the workspace libraries(typescript data libraries, non-angular libraries, etc.).

Comment: I tried your solution and it didn't work as of Nov/2021

Comment: For anyone following this in the future... while I didn't need to delete node_modules, it could be that you just need to delete `node_modules/.cache/nx` instead of the whole tree

Answer (score 1):

DON'T play with NX configuration. Just delete `dist` and `node_modules` and install again. I think it is a bug that they need to fix

Answer (score 0):

For those that upgraded from nx 6/7 to 8 or 9 you may need to verify your angular.json for libraries is is using `"builder": "@nrwl/angular:package",` instead of `"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",`. Without this change the system will attempt to use the angular-cli builder which has no knowledge of the rest of the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with the idea of chabu, but I only do an `npm i` without deleting the `node_modules` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue, I have forget to write ".ts" extension of a file and VSCode has auto interprete the file as a TS file.

So, in my case, just fix the extension file by adding ".ts" solve my issue.